# How to query MongoDB to see if a field (string) matches an element in an array (of strings)?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have an array of strings and I want to find all documents that have a field with the value that is contained in a an array.

For example, say I have the array `kidsInTrouble = ["Jerry", "Tom", "Arnold"]`,

I want to search through my Students collection to find all the kids who's `name` field is either `"Jerry"`, 
`"Tom"`, or `"Arnold"`.

(Bonus points if a solution can be provided using Spring's Mongo Driver methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator like this:

```
var kidsInTrouble = ["Jerry", "Tom", "Arnold"]
db.collection.find({name: {$in: kidsInTrouble}})
```

Check out this answer for an example using the $in operator from Java:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347298/6440033

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like below:

```
db.students.find({"name": {$in:[$your_variable]})
```