# Optimize MongoDB call

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection and I am using java driver to fetch the data from the mongo collection.

I have a list of phone numbers with me and I need to search the mongoDB collection for all those mobile numbers.

Let's say I have 500 mobile numbers, currently from my java code , I will say :

```
List<String> mobilenumbers = getMobileNumbers();   //lets assume this list length is 500
for(int i=0;i<= mobilenumbers.size(); i++){

    mongoDB.find(mobilenumbers.get(i);
}
```

Now the problem is I am hitting DB **500 times..**

I would like to know if there is any better way to handle  like for example in RDBMS we do like below

```
select * from mobiles where mobile_number in ( 'xxx','yyy','zzz'.......)
```

So single call is enough like above query but there's a limit for number of arguments to be passed in SQL in IN clause.. I remember some 300 etc but depends on which RDBMS..

Now , for MongoDB do we have any such limit for Filter ?   What's the best way to reduce DB hits?

Comment: What is your mongoDB Java Driver?

Comment: we use custom driver developed by my org...btw, how does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Use [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or [$in (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#-in--).

Like this answer: [How to use $in operator in mongodb with two fields in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347156/16706782)

Comment: I know this.. but what if I have 1000 elements to be used in  "IN" operator... is there a limit ?  or is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35601632/16706782

Comment: @thanks Sina..  the answer in the link says we run into problems if the parameters are in millions.. what kind of problems do we run into is not mentioned though?   and the answer is 5 years old... so is the issue fixed in recent mongo DB verisions??

Comment: I just took 500 as example in my question..  in production it will definitely be in millions..  so  the  $in operator  misbehaves as mentioned in the link you have provided.

Comment: No it's still 16MBs yet but in my opinion you can split your list to several packets and run query on each packet (in for loop) then merge results, for example: 1 million split it to 100 packets with 10000 length.